# repeat a vector up to the nth element

Tags: r, loops, vector, seq, rep

The vector i want to repeat is :

```
> months2014
[1] "07" "08" "09" "10" "11" "12"
```

I want to repeat it based on this vector which defines the nth values:

```
> num_times
  [1]  6  6  6  6  5  6  6  5  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6
 [33]  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6 12  6  6  6  6  6  6  6 12  6  6  6  6  6  6
 [65]  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6 12  6
 [97]  6  6 12  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6 12  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  2  6  6
[129]  6 12  6  6  6  6  6  6
```

I used this loop to get the below output:

```
for (i in num_times)  
  print(months2014[1:i])

[1] "07" "08" "09" "10" "11" "12"
[1] "07" "08" "09" "10" "11" "12"
[1] "07" "08" "09" "10" "11" "12"
[1] "07" "08" "09" "10" "11" "12"
[1] "07" "08" "09" "10" "11" ## repeated upto the 5th element
[1] "07" "08" "09" "10" "11" "12"
[1] "07" "08" "09" "10" "11" "12"
[1] "07" "08" "09" "10" "11" ## repeated up to the 6th element
```

If you look at the num_times vector, it also has 12. Because of this I also get this result:

```
[1] "07" "08" "09" "10" "11" "12" NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

There are only 6 elements in `months2014` so I get NAs. I actually want it to restart and get output like this:

```
[1] "07" "08" "09" "10" "11" "12" "07   "08" "09"   "10"   "11"   "12"
```

I have three questions:

1) How do I save the loop output? I tried creating an empty vector and putting the results into it but that didn't work:

```
temp_vec <- c()
for (i in num_times)  
  temp_vec <- print(months2014[1:i])
```

2) How do I fix the NA ?

3) There must be a better way of doing this?

Comment: Maybe `sapply(num_times,function(x) rep(months2014,length.out=x))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After testing this seems to work:

```
sapply(num_times,function(x) rep(months2014,length.out=x)
```

It outputs a list and repeats the sequence if the value in `num_times` is higher than the length of `months214`:

```
[[1]]
[1] "07" "08" "09" "10" "11" "12"

[[2]]
[1] "07" "08" "09" "10" "11" "12"

[[3]]
[1] "07" "08" "09" "10" "11" "12"

[[4]]
[1] "07" "08" "09" "10" "11" "12"

[[5]]
[1] "07" "08" "09" "10" "11"

[[6]]
 [1] "07" "08" "09" "10" "11" "12" "07" "08" "09" "10" "11" "12"
```

Comment: that covers everything - removing the NA, using apply instead of loop . thanks ! I just added `c(unlist(sapply(num_times,function(x) rep(months2014,length.out=x))` to convert it to character

Comment: If the OP needs a vector output, another option is `months2014[sequence(num_times)]`